# how to sort table columns in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In controller:

`@orders=(Order.where(:hotel_user_id=>cookies[:hotel_id_for_login_user]))
   .order(params[:sort]).paginate(:per_page=>5,:page=>params[:page])`

In view:

```
<th style="color: #808080;font-size: 14px; ">
    <%= link_to "Created On",:sort=>"created_at"%>
</th>
```

I have a table with pagination and I want to sort its columns. I am referring to this tutorial ([http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?autoplay=true](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)). The problem is that sorting is not working and I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting results for the query and it's not sorting? Or are you not getting results at all?

Try this:

```
@orders = Order.where("hotel_user_id = ?", cookies[:hotel_id_for_login_user]).order("#{params[:sort]} ASC").paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

1. maybe your sort condition either needs to be a symbol or put in quotes
2. The "where" part of your query didn't set a condition
3. It's not safe to put in a user-provided variable directly into your conditions string because of potential SQL injection.

I'd recommend reading this for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I hope that helps!